# Why can't try catch work for some exceptions?

Tags: node.js

I have below code in a nodejs application. The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is used to create a user in firebase service. The problem is that the `try catch` doesn't work if there is an exception which is thrown from the method `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and it crashes my application. I wonder what the way to catch all errors in nodejs. Why doesn't `try catch` work in my case?

```
try {
                        return firebase
                            .auth()
                            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                    } catch (err) {
                        l.error(err);
                        return reject(err);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your methods are promise implemented then in that case you dont need to use try-catch block. take look at below sample code to achieve desire output.

let assume your method called `auth` or `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` are promise implemented as below. do same for auth

```
function createUserWithEmailAndPassword(param1,param2){
   return Promise(function(reject,resolve){

       //your code here
  })
}
```

then to call this method in such way that you can able to handle in exception/errors

```
return firebase
.then(function(result){
     return auth();
})
.then(function(result){
     return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
})
.then(function(result){
  //on success 
  resolve(result)
})
.catch(function(err){
       //handle all errors here
      reject(err)
})
```